# HTML5 Video Tag for .mov

Tags: html, video, .mov

I´m incorporating a video code in my project, but it doesn´t seem to work correctly. So I´ve made a very basic, simple page to test the code in order to see if I´m doing anything wrong.

Here´s the link:
http://swingostoso.com.br.temp-address.com/pt/TesteVideo01.html

The only thing that´s different on this code is that I´m trying to stream a .mov video file. Other formats work fine with a similar code. But not this onde.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You have correctly identified that the problem is the use of the mov file.

According to [MDN's *Media formats supported by the HTML audio and video elements*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats), only Safari supports the Quicktime video format.

The solution is to use a supported video format.

Comment: That´s very strange...because I remember that a few years ago, it would work by code...but thanks anyway!